# exit code `zero` not showing for right `Command `

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, mysql, database

I get below error but exit code shows `zero`  .  Is there a way to get exit code of db error. Because I will need to send email alert on basis of `exit code`  or `db error`

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `v_comloc`': View 'crais.v_comloc' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)
```

### My attempt

```
#!/bin/bash -x

mysqldump --opt --routines --single-transaction -p654321 -uroot -hlocalhost crais 2>>/var/log/failedJobs/mysqlCronJob.log |gzip -9 >/userBackupDrive/backupDatabases/crais.sql.gz

RESULT=$?
echo "Output code for $db is  : $RESULT "
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo
  else
    echo "$DATE__  $db backup not successful" >> /var/log/failedJobs/dbError.log
fi
```

Comment: Looks like this error is not critical in MySQL terms which means it returns 0. You could probably assign the mysqldump output to a variable and go from there.

Comment: Oracle has the same approach: if you just ran 200 queries in a session, a boolean result does not provide enough information. The method in Oracle is to redirect all output to a log, and search for error codes, which were always like ABC-12345 starting in column 1 (e.g. SQL-02045 No such table or view.) mySql may have a similar convention.